# Which reinforcement learning algorithm is applicable to a problem with a continuously variable reward and no intermediate rewards?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I think the title says it.  A "game" takes a number of moves to complete, at which point a total score is computed. The goal is to maximize this score, and there are no rewards provided for specific moves during the game. Is there an existing algorithm that is geared toward this type of problem?

EDIT: By "continuously variable" reward, I mean it is a floating point number, not a win/loss binary.  So you can't, for example, respond to "winning" by reinforcing the moves made to get there.  All you have is a number.  You can rank different runs in order of preference, but a single result is not especially meaningful.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, in my opinion, the title of your question seems a little confusing when you talk about "continuously variable reward". Maybe you could clarify this aspect.

On the other hand, without taking into account the previous point, it looks your are talking about the *temporal credit-assigment problem*: How do you distribute credit for a sequence of actions which only obtain a reward (positive or negative) at the end of the sequence?

E.g., a Tic-tac-toe game where the agent doesn't recive any reward until the game ends. In this case, almost any RL algorithm tries to solve the *temporal credit-assigment problem*. See, for example, Section 1.5 of [Sutton and Barto RL book](http://incompleteideas.net/book/RLbook2018.pdf), where they explain the working principles of RL and its advantages over other approaches using as example a Tic-tac-toe game.

Comment: See my edit.  Tic-tac-toe has a win loss, where my problem does not.  Consider, for example, a game where you use the controls to run and then jump and try to land as close to a target as possible, or perhaps jump the maximum distance.

Comment: Thanks for the update. In that case, why not reward the agent proportionally to the achieved goal. Following your example of the jump game, the reward could be the maximum if it lands exactly in the target (of if it achives the maximum possible distance), and then it descreases as you move away from the target. Does it make sense to you? Or I'm missunderstanding something?

Comment: In a general sense it makes sense to reward the agent proportionally to how far he jumps.  To add detail to the jump game analogy, the course is different each round and the maximum attainable distance is not known a priori.  I have a general understand of Q learning and policy gradient approaches, but I can't seem to fit this problem into those.  Do you think they are applicable, or do you have some other approach in mind?

Comment: Probably it is not a problem not knowing the maximum reward in advance. If you have a set of sequential actions that achieve a goal, probably RL is a good approach to take into account. Q-learning vs policy gradient depends on other problem features, e.g., if the action space is discrete or continuous.